# Error: The program miktex-pdftex.exe was not found!

Tags: errors, compiling, miktex, texworks

My TeXworks doesn't let me compile my documents anymore due to the error: `The program miktex-pdftex.exe was not found!`:

[image: Texworks-error-message]

It is OK in TeXnicCenter but not here.

I looked up the net to download the missing part, but couldn't find it. Any thoughts?

Comment: In a working miktex miktex-pdftex.exe can't be missing. So either you don't have miktex installed, or it is completly broken, or the PATH settings are wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I only needed to change the path given in the preference. I don't why it happened. It used to work fine. :-)

Comment: @Vahid: Glad your problem was solved. Could you add a little description of how you solved the problem as an answer to this question? (Also, don't forget the `@username` when responding to someone's comment!)

Comment: Nice to see that the problem is solved. As it was just a configuration issue, I will close the question as too localized.